# Amazon MWS Error 25 - Do You See An Error With My XML?

Tags: xml, amazon-mws, scratchpad

I'm trying to automate the shipping confirmation of our Amazon orders, but the submit feed says, "We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed.".

I've checked it against the documentation found here: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl.pdf

Can you please take a look?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
   <Header>
      <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
      <MerchantIdentifier>MY-MERCHANT-ID</MerchantIdentifier>
   </Header>
   <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
   <Message>
      <MessageID>1</MessageID>
      <OrderFulfillment>
         <AmazonOrderID>116-8390288-9796217</AmazonOrderID>
         <MerchantOrderID>877399</MerchantOrderID>
         <FulfillmentDate>2016-12-28T22:55:27-08:00</FulfillmentDate>
         <FulfillmentData>
            <CarrierName>USPS</CarrierName>
            <ShippingMethod>Standard</ShippingMethod>
         <ShipperTrackingNumber>9400110200830414375387</ShipperTrackingNumber>
         </FulfillmentData>
         <Item>
            <AmazonOrderItemCode>40322771766298</AmazonOrderItemCode>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
         </Item>
      </OrderFulfillment>
   </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML does not validate against the XSDs. `OrderFulfillment.xsd` contains the following passage:

```
<xsd:choice>
     <xsd:element ref="AmazonOrderID"/>
     <xsd:element ref="MerchantOrderID"/>
</xsd:choice>
```

meaning, you can only submit *either* an `AmazonOrderID` *or* your `MerchantOrderID`. The latter is only allowed if you made your own `MerchantOrderID` known to Amazon in a previous step. Since your system seems to know both, there is no reason not to use the `AmazonOrderID`.

The following XML feed validates and thus should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
   <Header>
      <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
      <MerchantIdentifier>MY-MERCHANT-ID</MerchantIdentifier>
   </Header>
   <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
   <Message>
      <MessageID>1</MessageID>
      <OrderFulfillment>
         <AmazonOrderID>116-8390288-9796217</AmazonOrderID>

         <FulfillmentDate>2016-12-28T22:55:27-08:00</FulfillmentDate>
         <FulfillmentData>
            <CarrierName>USPS</CarrierName>
            <ShippingMethod>Standard</ShippingMethod>
         <ShipperTrackingNumber>9400110200830414375387</ShipperTrackingNumber>
         </FulfillmentData>
         <Item>
            <AmazonOrderItemCode>40322771766298</AmazonOrderItemCode>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
         </Item>
      </OrderFulfillment>
   </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```